# Scope variable is not working in html template in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass the `variation variable` from `card.html` to `tooltip.html` in angulajs. However, for whatever reasons, it doesn't work. When I `console.log(scope.variation)` inside `interestRateTooltip.directive.js`, it is showing me `apr`.

Also, in `tooltip.html`, if I have the following

```
<div>
  {{ variation }}
</div>
```

it is displaying `apr` inside a div. So I don't understand why `<i tooltip position="{{ variation === 'apr' ? 'left' : 'right'}}">` would always be false and becomes `right`.

I have spent 6 hours searching since this morning. Can someone please help? Thanks!

In `card.html`

```
<div>
  <interest-rate-tooltip variation="apr"></interest-rate-tooltip>
</div>
```

In `interestRateTooltip.directive.js`

```
angular.module("borrower.offers").directive('interestRateTooltip',  function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: ".../card.html",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (attrs.variation === 'apr') {
        scope.variation = 'apr';
      }
    }
  }
});
```

In `tooltip.html`

```
<div>
  <i tooltip position="{{ variation === 'apr' ? 'left' : 'right'}}">
</div>
```

In `tooltip.directive.js`

```
angular.module("borrower.offers")
  .directive("tooltip", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var params = {};

        switch (attrs.position) {
          case 'left':
            params = { position: 'bottom left' }
            break;
          case 'right':
            params = { position: 'bottom right' }
            break;
          case 'center':
            params = { position: 'bottom center' }
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi @lealceldeiro - sorry i don't get what you are saying. Would you mind elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Don't mind me. I didn't read properly before. I think you need a way to get the two directives to communicate between them. Right now the `variation` you got in `<i tooltip position="{{ variation === 'apr' ? 'left' : 'right'}}">` is not the same variable in `<interest-rate-tooltip variation="apr"></interest-rate-tooltip>`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably because you're accessing the `attrs.position` inside the link function for the directive. As the link function only triggers once, at the time it's triggered, your `attrs.position` is `right` because the `variation` is probably undefined. You can add the `$timeout` to your directive and wrap the content of the link function inside it, forcing a digest.

It would be something like this:

```
.directive("tooltip", ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
return {
  restrict: "A",
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    $timeout(function() {
        var params = {};

      switch (attrs.position) {
        case 'left':
          params = { position: 'bottom left' }
          break;
        case 'right':
          params = { position: 'bottom right' }
          break;
        case 'center':
          params = { position: 'bottom center' }
          break;
      }
    });
   }
  }
}]);
```

This will probably solve your problem, but also someone might think in a better solution.